# How to paste the keyframes of one animation at the end of another

Tags: animation, keyframes

So I have an object with 4 different idle animations. I want to combine these into one animation which has one playing after the other.

[image]

I succeed in combining them using the NLA editor, by dragging them one after another. But this is not what I want, as this makes an NLA track that consists of 4 animations. I want them to become 1 animation, placing the keyframes one of another.

How do I achieve such a feat?

[image]

This is the reason I cannot use multiple strips in 1 NLA track. The GLTF export cannot export those.
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/763

Comment: so what happens if you try to copy paste the keyframes in the Dope Sheet? It should work...

Answer (score 0):

1. tap on your second action to select

[image]

2.) tap <kbd>G</kbd> and move it with the mouse to the right

[image]

3.) repeat steps 1-2 with all other animations you want to move

Comment: That creates an NLA track consisting of 2 or more actions. Normally that is fine, but for my use case, when I export the scene, NLA tracks consisting of multiple actions cannot be imported in my end use engine. It needs to be 1 action by moving the actual keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to copy the keyframes. Turns out my problem was actually the selecting all keyframes of 1 action.

So:

1. Select Idle 1 in Action Editor
2. Make sure 'Only show selected' is disabled, otherwise you will only select 1 bone (see screenshot).
3. Left menu select 'summary' (so all keyframes of all bones are included)
4. CTRL click the earliest (most left) keyframe, CTRL click the latest (most right) keyframe.
5. CTRL + C copy
6. Select Idle 2 in Action Editor
7. Put the timeline horizontal line at the last keyframe of Idle 2.
8. Control + V pase
9. Push down into its own action.
10. Enjoy chained idle animations

[image]